# Insert current date into buffer

Tags: functions, user-commands, date-and-time

I want to insert current date into buffer.

I did in my `.vimrc` - it works:

```
nnoremap <F5> "=strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z")<CR>P
```

But how can I create a Vim command (e.g.: `:insertdate`) that does the same?

Because CLI vim via SSH doesn't handle Fn keys, as it seems.
(Or at least in my setup.)

Comment: Nitpicking: you're not looking for a function but for a user command. I took the liberty to tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that.

Comment: As for the Fn key issue: that's probably off-topic here. And we would need a lot more information to solve it.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further. Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking to create a user command as documented in `:help user-command`.

User commands have to start with an upper-case letter to disambiguate them from the built-in commands. So `:insertdate` is off the table but e.g. `:InsertDate` would work.

I believe the following command would answer your question

```
:command! InsertDate normal! i<C-R>=strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z")<CR>
```

This is a slight variation on your (and Vivian's) mapping. It enters insert mode and uses the expression register through `<C-R>=`.

### Functions vs. User Commands

The question originally asked for a function to do this. This is also  possible but is far less convenient. The function's body would look almost like the command above but it would have to be called using `:call insertdate()`. Nobody wants to type that.

Comment: Probably `normal!` unless you need `normal`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble no, just sloppiness. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2):

The custom command must start with an upper case:

You can create the corresponding `InsertDate` command like:

```
command! InsertDate normal! "=strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z")<CR>P
```

Comment: Damn your FTL answers... I was just typing it out :-D

Comment: Sorry for that :-| I should have guessed ;-)

Comment: No need to apologize... it's a game. Fastest wins :-) And mine also looks more clumsy :-)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a user command, here are my insert-mode abbreviations for inserting a timestamp:

```
:iab <expr> dts strftime("%F %R")    " Date/time stamp
:iab <expr> dtg strftime("%e %b %Y") " Date style used in genealogy
```

(I'm a bit of a genealogy guy, but I've never used the second one in vim.)